# How to add or\and edit translation files for an android system Rom?

Tags: android, hebrew, firmware, rom

I am in Israel, using the Hebrew language, and I purchase phones from the USA.
Recently Samsung decided not to show all language, but just the region important ones, in order to block imports from other countries I suppose.

I am new to android development, but I would like to know how to add or\and edit a System translation file, in order to maybe change a custom or stock Rom and have Hebrew language.

Thanks!

Comment: THis isn't really a programming question.  Try android.stackexchange.com instead.  IIRC, you can add a locale, but if you don't have translations for it they will show in the default language (usually english, for Samsung may be Korean).  Those translations may or may not be in the ROM.  And you may have odd results with english translations in a right to left language.

Comment: Ok I will ask in android.stackexchange, thanks.
But my question was how to ADD the translation system language. adding the Locale is incomplete on Samsung devices for example..